# Routes for edit not working ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, routes

Hi am trying to edit/update some data in the database but I keep getting the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/books/11/edit"
```

I tried adding some different lines the routes.rb such as

```
post 'books/edit'
```

etc.. but am having no luck. Here is my current Routes file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :books, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :index]

  resources :details, :only => [:new, :edit]

  resources :members

  devise_for :users 

  get 'page/books'

  get 'page/about'

  get 'page/contact'

  get 'page/home'

  post "details/new"

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   root 'page#home'
```

My Def Edit is :

```
  def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end
```

And the form am using to used is:

```
<h4> Book Details </h4>

<p> Edit This Current Book </p>
<%= form_for @book do |f| -%>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :isbn_number %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :isbn_number, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :author, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :status, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <br />
    <%= f.submit "Edit Book" %>
<% end -%>

  <br />
```

==Worked after adding this==
Def Update:

```
def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book.update_attributes(book_params)
    redirect_to new_book_path
  end
```

Comment: When does this error come up? Is it when you try and submit the form?

Comment: I can't get to the form page, as soon as I click edit which should links me to the edit page the error occurs

Comment: OK, sounds like a problem with your edit link. This should be generating a GET request not a POST. Are you using something like `link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book)`?

Comment: yea, it seems to be working now, I needed to add an update action, but I thought I should still be able to see the form without it but guess now. Anyway I added the update I used to the question and it fixed the error. along with `resources :books, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :index]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is rendered with `edit` action, but it is submitted to `update` action as `PUT` request. You need to implement it in your controller and handle it in routes.

```
resources :books, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :index]
```

Comment: I was thinking that even with having the update action, I should at least be able to view the form and only when I try to submit should it fail because the update isn't implement yet, but I will try add it in now and see

Comment: I added an update action and it works now thank you :D!!